# TypeError: Cannot read property 'fraction' of undefined - Cypress/Javascript

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am doing a test where I grab an odds value and store it as a fraction. Then I want to compare the value to a particular format depending on the option selected from the drop down.

I am trying to use these to set up the fraction and determine the odds format:

https://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/fractions.html

How do I resolve that type error above.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You should only ask one question.

Comment: Ah no worries, I updated the question to just include 1 question :)

Comment: Have you determined what's going wrong with the mathjs `import`? The error means that `math` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy So I know the npm install was fine, looks like it's imported mathjs fine but don't know again why undefined. I included a screenshot above

Comment: If mathjs had been imported "fine" then `math` would not be `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy but I don't know what else I can do, I followed the documentation to npm install it and them imported it based on the example it mentioned and I can see in the package json it shows mathjs with its version

Comment: You use different paths for the other packages you import; are you sure that simply "mathjs" is the correct path?

Comment: [This documentation](https://mathjs.org/docs/getting_started.html) suggests that you have to **create** an instance of `math`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mathjs` has no default export, so you import everything (`*`) and then name it in your import

```js
import * as math from 'mathjs'
```

---

This is the main entry point for the `mathjs` package.

```js
// configuration
export { config } from './configReadonly.js'

// functions and constants
export * from './pureFunctionsAny.generated.js'
export * from './impureFunctionsAny.generated.js'
export * from './typeChecks.js'

// error classes
export { IndexError } from '../error/IndexError.js'
export { DimensionError } from '../error/DimensionError.js'
export { ArgumentsError } from '../error/ArgumentsError.js'

// dependency groups
export * from './dependenciesAny.generated.js'

// factory functions
export * from '../factoriesAny.js'

// core
export { create } from '../core/create.js'
export { factory } from '../utils/factory.js'
```

If it had a default export, there would be

```js
export default {
  function1,
  function2,
  function3,
  ...
}
```

and then you can import it without using `* as math`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use just `fraction` you can use:

```js
const { fraction } = require("mathjs");

//In your test
fraction(oddsValue);
```

If you want to use others as well, you can do:

```js
import { create, all } from "mathjs"
const math = create(all, {})

//In your test
math.fraction(oddsValue)
```